# I am getting error in angular. Any suggestion?

Tags: angular, compiler-errors

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMWuy.png)

After doing ng serve if I open localhost:4200, I am getting the above error on the browser. Here are the dependencies I am using,

"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.7",
"@angular/animations": "9.1.9",
"@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
"@angular/common": "9.1.9",
"@angular/compiler": "9.1.9",
"@angular/core": "9.1.9",
"@angular/flex-layout": "9.0.0-beta.31",
"@angular/forms": "9.1.9",
"@angular/material": "9.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.9",
"@angular/router": "9.1.9",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "14.0.0",
"android-versions": "1.5.0",
"chart.js": "2.9.3",
"core-js": "3.6.5",
"d3": "5.16.0",
"firebase": "7.14.2",
"hammerjs": "2.0.8",
"localforage": "1.7.3",
"neutrinos-module": "0.0.55",
"neutrinos-oauth-client": "1.2.1",
"ng2-charts": "2.3.2",
"node-sass": "4.14.1",
"rxjs": "6.5.5",
"signature_pad": "2.3.2",
"tslib": "1.13.0",
"zone.js": "0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.7",
"@angular/cli": "9.1.7",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.9",
"@angular/language-service": "9.1.9",
"@types/googlemaps": "3.39.13",
"@types/jasmine": "3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
"@types/node": "12.12.42",
"codelyzer": "6.0.0",
"gulp": "4.0.2",
"gulp-cordova-create": "2.0.1",
"gulp-cordova-version": "0.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "5.0.9",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
"karma-cli": "2.0.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "3.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
"protractor": "7.0.0",
"sw-precache": "5.2.1",
"ts-node": "8.3.0",
"tslint": "6.1.0",
"typescript": "3.8.3"
}

Comment: you have some error in template can you share it ?

Comment: @malbarmavi I have added an image. Kindly check.